# Is flask-security concerned with User table only?

Tags: python, flask-security

Am asking a very simple, rather a silly, question about flask-security.
 I have read docs, researched stackoverflow questions, but I really didn't get anything
 except that - Flask-security handles login/logout of the Users, along with
certain other related functions.
Is it concerned only with Users table in the database?
What about other tables, for eg. in a banking website there are `Branch`, `Accounts`, `city`...
How do I use these tables if I want to use Flask-security, am really confused?

Flask-security is very new to me, 
any help from you guys would be deeply appreciated,
 thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Flask Security comes with a User and Role Model out of the box [See here for a quick overview](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/quickstart.html), but you can also create your own custom models and even extend the User to include additional fields.

It all depends on what you are trying to build & how advanced your current Python/Flask skill set is.

What it is really good at, is giving you some predefined automation for user setup, to stop you from building everything from scratch. Not sure if this helps, but hope it does.